# Google maps api key - limits

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Will my API key be blocked for rest of the day when I reach the daily requests limit? I don't want to buy billing plan or get unexpected charges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_exceed

You won't be charged, but your API will return an error message.

Answer (score 0):

It is my impression that as you approach your daily quota limit the system starts giving errors. For example, during the last 4 hours of the day the errors gradually increase with perhaps 100% errors during the last hour.

Most days the total allowed requests has been within my quota. One day it went over, like 2645 versus my 2500 daily quota.

I have tried to spread the error misery evenly around the world by limiting the accesses to 3 per 100 secs. This may be working but I have not seen any errors shown on the graphs as being due to exceeding the 100 secs quotas, which is surprising since I am often exceeding 0.04 requests per sec (5 min average).